# Sent mail in Lotus Notes

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I just started using Lotus Notes (normally I use Outlook) and I'm confused and bothered about something: the "sent" folder is some sort of 'view', and not an actual folder (unlike Outlook).  I like to file away my sent messages into the same folders as my received messages so that I have them all together in one area.  I can 'move' sent messages to folders, but they stay in the 'sent' view, which is infuriating because now I have no idea if I've filed them all away or not.

What can I do to make a sent email appear in a given folder but NOT in the sent view?

Comment: Why you started using Lotus Notes?

Comment: because I started at a new company that uses Lotus Notes/Domino

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000514.html

Comment: No, I'm not quitting this company because they use Lotus Notes.  I'd rather make lemonade with lemons.

Comment: Of course. I just wanted you to know that we feel the pain. On the other side, I heard there a many things you can do with Notes which you can't with other programs, like... ehm... ;-)

Comment: Upon seeing "Lotus Notes" I misread the question as "Send mail in Lotus Notes", which sounds just as valid a question for superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete a note from your sent view, you should get the message:

> You are about to delete document(s)
>   from the view as well as from all
>   folders to which this document
>   belongs.
>
> Continue deleting these documents or
>   only remove them from this view?

Then, 3 buttons Delete Remove Cancel
and a check box for "Don't ask me again (I can change it later)"

If you pick remove, it will remove it from the sent view and keep the one you moved.

But something you should look into is the amount of space you are given.   Saving everything takes up space, so you may want to look into using the Archive feature.

Comment: Yes, archiving is an issue whether I use Outlook or Notes.  Thank you very much for a great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found a link on IBM.com site that may be better:

[Creating a Sent Mail Folder](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Creating_a_Sent_Mail_folder/)

Answer (score 2):

Found a compromise solution that makes it bearable (at least for me).

1. Go to File, Preferences, Mail, Sending and Receiving and change *Save copies of messages that I send* to *Never*.
2. Then, in File, Preferences, Mail, Basics, *When I delete any document in the Sent view*, change that to: *Remove without deleting*. *OK* to close and save changes.

Now by default, if you just click *Send* your message is not saved anywhere. If you want to file a copy of the message, click instead on *Send and file...* and choose the folder where you want to file the message. Your *sent view* will still get populated with those messages, but since you configured 2), you can just go there and remove the messages from time to time (they'll still be on the folder you filed them). I guess you could also set up some script to delete things in the sent view periodically.